# Extracting data from netCDF file using python

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf

unfortunately I'm quite new to python and don't have time at the moment to dig deeper, so that I can't understand and solve the error displayer by the python console. I am trying to use this code to extract data from multiple netCDF-files for multiple locations:

```py
#this is for reading the .nc in the working folder
import glob
#this is reaquired ti read the netCDF4 data
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
#required to read and write the csv files
import pandas as pd
#required for using the array functions
import numpy as np


# Record all the years of the netCDF files into a Python list
all_years = []

for file in glob.glob('*.nc'):
    print(file)
    #reading the files
    data = Dataset(file, 'r')
    #saving the data variable time
    time = data.variables['time']
    #saving the year which is written in the file
    year = time.units[11:15]
    #once we have acquired the data for one year then it will combine it for all the years as we are using for loop here
    all_years.append(year)

# Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame covering the whole range of data and then we will read the required data and put it here
year_start = min(all_years) 
end_year = max(all_years)
date_range = pd.date_range(start = str(year_start) + '-01-01', 
                           end = str(end_year) + '-12-31', 
                           freq = 'D')

#an empty having 0.0 values dataframe will be created with two columns date_range and temperature
df = pd.DataFrame(0.0, columns = ['Precipitation'], index = date_range)
    

# Defining the names, lat, lon for the locations of your interest into a csv file
#this will read the file locations
locations = pd.read_csv('stations_locations.csv')

#we would use a for loop as we are interested in aquiring all the information one by one from the rows
for index, row in locations.iterrows():
    # one by one we will extract the information from the csv and put it into temp. variables
    location = row['names']
    location_lat = row['latitude']
    location_lon = row['longitude']

# Sorting the all_years just to be sure that model writes the data correctly
    all_years.sort()
    
    
    #now we will read the netCDF file and here I have used netCDF file from FGOALS model
    for yr in all_years:
        # Reading-in the data 
        data = Dataset('pr_day_CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_%s0101-%s1231.nc'%(yr,yr), 'r')
    
        # Storing the lat and lon data of the netCDF file into variables 
        lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
        lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
        
        #as we already have the co-ordinates of the point which needs to be downloaded
        #in order to find the closest point around it we need to substract the cordinates
        #and check which ever has the minimun distance
        # Squared difference between the specified lat,lon and the lat,lon of the netCDF 
        sq_diff_lat = (lat - location_lat)**2 
        sq_diff_lon = (lon - location_lon)**2
    
        # Identify the index of the min value for lat and lon
        min_index_lat = sq_diff_lat.argmin()
        min_index_lon = sq_diff_lon.argmin()
    
        # Accessing the average temparature data
        temp = data.variables['pr']
    
        # Creating the date range for each year during each iteration
        start = str(yr) + '-01-01'
        end = str(yr) + '-12-31'
        d_range = pd.date_range(start = start, 
                            end = end, 
                            freq = 'D')
    
        for t_index in np.arange(0, len(d_range)):
            print('Recording the value for: ' + str(location)+'_'+ str(d_range[t_index]))
            df.loc[d_range[t_index]]['Temparature'] = temp[t_index, min_index_lat, min_index_lon]

    df.to_csv(str(location) + '.csv')
```

This is the error code displayed:

```
File "G:\Selection Cannon\Historical\CNRM-CM5_r1i1p1\pr\extracting data_CNRM-CM5_pr.py", line 62, in <module>
    data = Dataset('pr_day_CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_%s0101-%s1231.nc'%(yr,yr), 'r')

  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 2321, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__

  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1885, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'pr_day_CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_18500101-18501231.nc'
```

When I check the variable/function 'time.units' it says "days since 1850-1-1", but I just have files from 1975-2005 in the folder. And if I check "all_years" it just displayes '1850' seven times. I think this has to do with the "year = time.units[11:15]" line, but this is how the guy in the youtube video did it.
Can someone please help me to solve this, so that this code extracts the files from 1975 and on?

Best regards,
Alex

PS: This is my first post, please tell me if you need any supplemtary informations and data :)

Comment: Edit: I managed to get an csv.file, but starting with '01-01-1850' and ending with '12-31-1850'. Normally it should start with '01-01-1979" and end with '12-31-2005', but I cant get python to extract the years 1975-2005 from the files in the file-order. Is it possible that I have to supply the whole dataset, starting with the year 1850, for python in order to use the method I want to use?

Comment: I've tried your script, and there is an error ```ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp``` related to this section: ```date_range = pd.date_range(start = str(year_start) + '-01-01',    end = str(end_year) + '-12-31',        freq = 'D')```. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, it seems like you didn't give the correct path. Should be something like "G:/path/to/pr_day_CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_18500101-18501231.nc".

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems to "work" without giving the path, as the script is located in the same folder as the files I want to extract. However I still can't get it to start from 1979.

Comment: @BierBaron this works untill this error ```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-f1b15fd46368> in <module>
     29         for t_index in np.arange(0, len(d_range)):
     30             print('Recording the value for: ' + str(location)+'_'+ str(d_range[t_index]))
---> 31             df.loc[d_range[t_index]]['Temparature'] = temp[t_index, min_index_lat, min_index_lon]
     32 
     33 df.to_csv(str(location) + '.csv')

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__()

IndexError: index exceeds dimension bounds```